# reciprocal functions of reciprocal functions

Tags: functions

I've been working with reciprocal functions, but have come across 2 different perspectives for the reciprocal of a reciprocated function. Do restrictions on the original function apply to the reciprocal?

eg.

$ f(x)=\frac{1}{x} $

if   $g(x)$ is the reciprocal function of  $f(x)$

is $g(x)$ continuous or discontinuos as $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$?

would this be different for

$g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$

or

$g(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$

Answer (score 1):

This essentially depends on which domain you give the *reciprocal function* of $g$. By definition of the reciprocal, $f(x)$ is only defined on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ (where it is non-zero) and hence its reciprocal $g(x)$ will only be unambiguously defined on this same set. Indeed, it does not make sense to define
$$
g(x) := \frac{1}{f(x)}
$$
where $f(x)$ does not exist.

However, as you have noted, one has $g(x) = x$ for all $x \neq 0$. Thus, $g$ has a unique continuous extension $\tilde{g}$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
\tilde{g}(x) = x \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Although these $g$ and $\tilde{g}$ agree at all points $x \neq 0$, they are not technically the same functions/objects as $g$ is not defined at $x=0$. Consequently, it does not make sense to discuss the continuity of $g$ at $0$. But, as mentioned above, this does not prevent the existence of a continuous extension on all of $\mathbb{R}$.